# Delete text from copied text

Tags: javascript, copy, copy-paste

I would like to use JavaScript to clean up text that’s being copied from my site.

I use snippets like this:

```
body {
    vertical-align: middle; ➊
}
```

Where ➊ indicates comment later on. I want readers to copy this snippet and use it – so I need to delete that Unicode marker. How can I access text that’s being copied and make changes to it?

I considered deleting marker(s) from snippet when user clicks (mousedown) on it, so she could select the text, copy it and then I would restore markers but it seems a really long way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the unicode markers in span tags, and put display none on them when the user clicks

```
body {
    vertical-align: middle; <span class="marker">➊</span>
}
```

And then do this in jQuery

```
$('.code')
    .mousedown(function() {
        $(this).find('.marker').css('display','none');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).find('.marker').css('display','inline');
    });
```

As a bonus, you could then apply the following style to the `.marker` elements:

```
​.marker
{
    position:absolute;   
    right:0;
}​
```

Comment: IMHO this seams to be the most resonable way! +1

Comment: Have you tested it successfully? I can’t make it work (I’m proficient with JavaScript, so code executes but I still copy markers.)

Comment: Not in Safari & Firefox, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You could turn the unicode marker into an image, as images are ignored when copying plain text.

Comment: That’s actually something I might try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just set the markers in comment? so it doesn't do any harm when being used after copying

Comment: Thumbs up for the idea, but that’s not what I’m looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [oncopy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.oncopy) handler, but I doubt it is widely supported. There are also selection event handlers like [onselectstart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536969%28VS.85%29.aspx) (again, different for different browsers) and various attributes to make a part of the text unselectable, like [-moz-user-select: none](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/-moz-user-select) (yet again, not cross-browser). You are probably better of using absolutely positioned markers or making the marker unaccessible through z-index.

Comment: User-select: none works in Mozilla and WebKit and yes, it doesn’t select markers. But they’re copied anyway. :/